# Keep getting Spring context lookup failed, skipping spring component provider initialization in Intellij

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-data

I have keep getting  Spring context lookup failed, skipping spring component provider initialization in jetty server logs. I did my research on the topic and found out that I should use annotations in order to tell Spring Data and Spring to recognise my Spring components.

The result of not recognising my components is that the repository is empty. Thank you in advance.

This is my REST endpoint

```
@Component
//@ComponentScan("com.myapp.controller.TestEndpoint")
@Path("/test")
public class TestEndpoint {

@Autowired
private UserRepository repository;

  @Bean
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String test() {
       User user = new User("Ivan", "Ivanov");
      repository.save(user);
      return "Ok! Working!";
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on main initializer class.

Comment: I suppose your suggestion works if I am using Spring boot, but in my case I am using Spring. What is the equivalent a notation there?